# Azure CDN convert images to webp

Tags: azure, azure-cdn

I looked over the following documentation from Azure (https://docs.azure.cn/en-us/cdn/cdn-image-processing) and am not sure if I am reading this correctly.  My problem is that I am looking to serve images that are being requested from the cdn, which are stored in a blob storage, in webp format instead of jpeg/png etc., but have been unsuccessful.

Ideally I would like to add a query param such as `?format=webp`, but this doesn't seem to be working.  Does anybody know how I can convert my images on the fly from an azure cdn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this feature is only available for Azure China CDN.
You can use other image CDN such as cloudnary/imgx. Unfortunately there is no Azure equivalent as AWS lambda @ Edge.